# jackson prints empty JSON string

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson

I have a java program which should serialize objects using jackson (play framework). It was working, but I messed it up somehow and now I can't get it working. Here is my serializer

```java
public String serializeObject(Object object) {
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = null;
    try {
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

and here is the code which runs it:

```java
return badRequest(serializeObject(new Error("bad input")));
```

and the error class:

```java
public class Error {
    private String error;

    public Error(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

and as the output, all I get is `{ }`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `Error Class`'s properties need to have setter and getters which you want to show in `JSON` output

```java
public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}
```